# French proverb for "too many cooks spoil the broth"

Tags: proverbes

Is there a French proverb equivalent to "too many cooks spoil the broth"?

Y a-t-il un proverbe français équivalent à "too many cooks spoil the broth" ? J'ai des analogies avec l'armée mexicaine, mais pas sous forme proverbiale...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'expression française consacrée est

> Trop de cuisiniers gâtent la sauce

Il y a néanmoins débat pour savoir s'il convient de l'écrire ainsi ou plutôt au singlulier:

> Trop de cuisiniers gâte la sauce

Après quelques recherches on retrouve le plus souvent la forme plurielle, mais de mon côté je trouve la forme au singulier plus correcte. En effet, c'est le fait d'avoir trop de cuisiniers qui gâte la sauce. On pourrait sans changer le sens dire

> L'excès de cuisiniers gâte la sauce
>
> Quand trop de cuisiniers y travaillent, ça gâte la sauce.

Si par contre on disait

> Trop de cuisiniers ne se lavent pas les mains avant de travailler

Le pluriel est obligatoire, ce sont en effet les cuisiniers, individuellement, qui ne se lavent pas les mains.

Enfin au moins vous avez une réponse pour l'oral...

Note: cette expression n'est à ma connaissance pas pas très courante. Pour tout vous dire sans avoir fait de recherche pour répondre je ne l'aurais jamais entendue...

Comment: en tout cas, en anglais, c'est un pluriel :)

Diriez vous "trop de cuisiniers font un mauvais bouillon" ou "trop de cuisiniers fait un mauvais bouillon"? A l'oreille, j'irais sur la première forme, même si elle peut être comprises de deux manières (celle du proverbe, ou une plainte de la baisse de niveau chez les cuisiniers...)

Comment: A l'oreille et en toute spontanéité je vous suivrais sur le "font", mais quoi que l'on en dise cela change le sens de la phrase, fut-ce en introduisant une ambiguïté qui est inexistante en utilisant la "bonne" forme.

Answer (score 2):

Je ne suis pas certain que l'expression corresponde parfaitement, mais je dirais :

> Un mauvais général vaut mieux que deux bons.

Citation qui vient apparemment de [Napoléon](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campagne_d%27Italie_(1796-1797)). C'est une expression relativement courante, je l'ai en tout cas beaucoup entendue.

Comment: J'avoue que je ne l'avais jamais entendue non plus mais à la lecture de l'article il semble que le sens soit similaire, donc que ca réponde également à l'OP.

Comment: j'aime bien, même si c'est la première fois que je la vois. Il y a un côté contre-pied à "un tien vaut mieux que deux tu l'auras"

Comment: Oui c'est une construction de phrase efficace! Pour ma part, je n'ai jamais entendu "Trop de cuisiniers gâtent la sauce".

Answer (score 2):

L'expression correspond à ce proverbe français:

> Trop de cuisiniers gâtent la sauce

Ce dernier s’emploie quand trop de personnes se consacrent à une même tâche et qu'il s'ensuit un échec. Dans le même style on trouve

> Quand il y a plusieurs cuisiniers, la soupe est trop salée.